# Cracking almonds without a nutcracker?

Tags: nuts, almonds

I got a bunch of (dried) almonds in their shell today. I wasn't aware of how hard their shells were and I have no nutcracker. Is there any way to open them without one?

[image]

Comment: Use pliers--preferably flatnose--as a nutcracker, if you have a pair.

Comment: Do you have pliers?  Clamps?  Vice grips? A hammer with a hard surface?

Comment: Actually none of the above at the moment. Not even a heavy cast iron pan. I tried to crack them between two cutting boards, but I couldn't keep the nut whole.

Comment: Rocks are hammers and anvils if you look at them right.  Wash carefully before use.  Smashed nutmeat may be a risk.  Also, avoid squirrels.

Comment: I've spent countless afternoons cracking almonds with rocks (or a hammer, when one was around). We use to do almond milk with them, yummy!

Comment: If the goal is to keep the nut meat whole, then you'll probably need to bite the bullet and get the right tool - either a nutcracker or pliers.  Borrow from a neighbor, friend or colleague?

Comment: also try squeezing the nuts against each other. Often one will crack.

Comment: If you have kitchen shears with the bottle opening indents behing the bladethat may work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

- Use common household tools (such as pliers) as improvised nutcrackers
- Try using the bottle gripper/opener on kitchen shears as an improvised nutcracker
- Use impact tools, such as a hammer, a heavy pan, or even cleaned rocks as nut smashers, but you may not get whole nutmeats with this method
- Bite the bullet and buy or borrow a nutcracker

(This is part of my little quest to get answers to some of the non-answered questions....)

Comment: Note another drawback of impact tools - the shell will fly in small pieces all around you at high speeds. Difficult to clean, and can scratch sensitive surfaces (shouldn't have enough power to hurt a person even with a very unlucky hit).

Answer (score 0):

Easy you just chuck it on any floor i just did 5 now

Comment: Presumably not _any_ floor will do. Possibly a tiled, stone or concrete floor. I also wonder how much time you spent looking for the freed nut and cleaning the floor post-shelling.